# Does a successful hit that does no damage due to DR still count as a hit?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, damage-resistance

I know that most special abilities or effects linked to an attack whose damage is entirely negated don't trigger, but does the attack still count as a hit in the first place with regard to abilities such as the combat feat Hammer the Gap?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Yes, you "hit" but do not "deal damage."**

The abilities which *are* negated due to not overcoming DR are those which have some effect correlated with damage. Poisons are a good example of this - if you don't actually make a wound, how are you going to poison them?

However, feats and abilities which are *not* negated if no damage is done, such as Hammer the Gap, are usually those which rely more on the *act* of actually hitting, rather than the effect. You can imagine Hammer the Gap being sort of "getting into a steady rhythm" with your strikes, even if no damage is done. (Like a boxer training on a punching bag.)

Answer (score 9):

**At GM Discretion.**

[Damage Reduction](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/special-abilities) reads:

> Whenever damage reduction completely negates the damage from an
>   attack, it also negates most special effects that accompany the
>   attack, such as injury poison, a monk's stunning, and injury-based
>   disease. Damage Reduction does not negate touch attacks, energy damage
>   dealt along with an attack, or energy drains. Nor does it affect
>   poisons or diseases delivered by inhalation, ingestion, or contact.
>
> Attacks that deal no damage because of the target's damage reduction
>   do not disrupt spells.

For purposes of [Hammer the Gap](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/hammer-the-gap-combat), it just requires you hit, so I'd say it's fine. Obviously there's GM interpretation here of what "most special effects" means, so there is no RAW-perfect answer except your GM's ruling.